# Tomcat connectionpool mysql configuration to avoid timeout of idle connections

Tags: mysql, scala, tomcat, jdbc, connection

I'm using tomcat 7 and the tomcat jdbc connection pool to dish out mysql connections.

During night times we don't have any activity so all connections become idle for longer than 8 hours and are dropped by mysql. (mysql's wait_timeout default).

We use the following pool configuration:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbName"
        auth="Container"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="50"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="5000"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        logAbandoned="true"
        username="xxx"
        password="xxx"
        url="jdbc:mysql://host:3306/xxx"/>
```

I was expecting the EvictionPolicy to remove idle connections way before they ever get closed by MySql. Somehow after one day we get the following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.

I guess this problem should be something the jdbc connection pool can fix, but there are many configuration properties and I haven't used this pool before. Anybody got a good set of properties to configure the pool to not dish out closed connections?

Kind regards,

Albert

Comment: Are you sure that your code is calling `connection.close()` on **every** connection inside the `finally` block of the `try` where it's been acquired from the pool?

Comment: I'm actually using the Lift framework (scala). Isn't opening/closing the connection something the pool should do (or not do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Turned out it wasn't a pooling problem after all. We were using squeryl and lift together which isn't a happy combi (just yet). Connections got closed before returned to the pool. 
Ditching lift's DB connection management in favor of squeryl's solved it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you did? Do you mean following this [pattern](https://github.com/migo/test-squerylrecord/blob/master/src/main/scala/test/KickTheTires.scala) and use new StandardDBVendor and DB.defineConnectionManager and I didn't see them use BoneCP.